# How can I align my Radiobutton list in a fieldset

Tags: asp.net, css, radiobuttonlist

I want to float my Radiobutton list but it gets very strange styling when I try to use 
float:left;

Any help appreciated? I want to align the radiobuttons and question on the same line
http://jsfiddle.net/MhHFH/2/

I'm using asp.net Radiobutton list so it creates automatic spans around it

```
<fieldset id="thirdForm">
        <legend>INFO</legend>
        <div class="rowDiv">
            <label>
                Question 1:
            </label>
            <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="rbCSS" ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: How do you want them to appear?Bit confused on that.

Comment: I want to have them on the same line. Question 1  * Yes * No

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MhHFH/2/

Answer (score 1):

Remove rdbtn css remove block then you can get the way you want